# python socket server is hanging after sending data

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server

I made a python socket server recently that listens on port 9777 the server is suppose to accept connections and once it does will allow you to send information to the client. The client will then print out whatever it received. However, I found that after I sent some data the server would hang until i reinitialized a new connection. Is there a reason for this and if so how can I prevent it from happening

The code of the server is :

```
import socket
import sys

host='0.0.0.0'
port=9777
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(10)
c,a=s.accept()
while True: 
    command=raw_input('[input>] ')
    if 'data' in command:
        c.send('continue')
        data=c.recv(1024)
        print data
    else:
        continue
```

the code will only send data if the word data is in the string. Here is the code for the client:

```
import socket
import sys

host='192.168.0.13'
port=9777
while True:
    try:    
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host,port))
    except:
        continue
    while True:
        d=s.recv(9999)
        print d
        s.send('received')
```

My goal is to setup a connection between server and client. I want the server to be able to accept input from a user in a while loop and send the input to the client. The client needs to be able to receive information and when it does it will send a response to the server. Then the user can continue sending data to the server until they decide to terminate the program. However the server keeps hanging after sending data once to the client. Can anyone tell me how I can prevent that?

Comment: Make sure you deal with the situation where send() and recv() don't return all data at once.  They return the number of bytes actually sent/received, and that number can be less than the number you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this code in my computer it's work fine , maybe you need to change `host='192.168.0.13'` to `host='localhost'`

and `host='0.0.0.0'` to `host='localhost'`

look at this picture [image]

and if this problem stay maybe your ip address is the same of other device in the network for that try to run this command `ipconfig /renew`